# Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json

I have two files. manifest.json and content.js. I have compressed the both files in Zip format and conver into CRX format.

Then just drag and drop the .crx file in Google chrome browser and continue to install the crx file. But it shows a alert message as "CRX_MAGIC_NUMBER_INVALID".

How to i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

> You need to be signed into your Google account in order to download extensions from the Web Store now. It's stupid, but this is the best way. [Source.](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/5zmoqHdSVJ4/PK3A_HUCqxwJ)

My friend had the same problem with installing a homebrew extension too. This should be the solution to your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a **pack extension option** in Chrome. Go to manage extension and there you will see that option. They will make the `.crx` file for you.

Answer (score 2):

Else you can do that using a batch file

```
cd /d C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome --pack-extension="[path of extensionfolder]" --no-message-box
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the format of your CRX file. The code

http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/sandboxed_extension_unpacker.cc

looks for a "magic number" at the start of the file, as detailed here

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/crx.html

It appears that it isn't (always) possible to zip your extension and rename it to crx. Perhaps something to do with the zip tool used? Anyway this thread discusses a very similar problem and solutions.

http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-apps/browse_thread/thread/1785b46c2998af2c