# Can't install my custom chrome extension crx_magic_number_invalid

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a simple chrome extension:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Layout VS Design",
  "version": "1",
  "description": "Enter the url of a image with your design at 100%",
  "background_page": "index.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Manipulate DOM",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "js.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

The thing is that chrome won't let me install it:
[image]

The thing is I  have no idea where to set this number, Any idea what can I try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I see is that your `background_page` isn't formatted properly. It should be

```
{ ...

   "background": {
       "page": "index.html"
    },
    ...
}
```

If you `manifest.json` file isn't formatted correctly, Chrome will reject the extension.

You can read more about the manifest formatting in the [Manifest File Format](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) documentation from Google.

## Update

[Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511699/google-chrome-extension) detailed how Chrome looks for a "magic number" at the top of a .crx file. But, if you're hosting locally, you can install extensions in a simpler manner.

- Save your `manifest.json` and `background.html` to a directory (the name doesn't matter)
- Go to `chrome:extensions`
- Make sure "Developer Mode" is checked at the top
- Click "Load unpacked extension..."
- Select the directory with your `background` and `manifest` files to install on Chrome.

Comment: Actually I get same error on any of those http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html is it my chrome?

Comment: I added an update to my answer on how to install local custom extensions without a .crx file.

Comment: Interesting! I would try and let you know! thanks for your time!

Comment: It's how I host all of my own extensions. I don't plan on releasing any, they're more for my own experimentation and workflow.

Comment: Interesting, For me, I added a page called background.html that just had my background.js script in it. This seems to solve the problem if you started out with a scripts: node.

Answer (score 2):

1. go to extensions page
2. check developer options
3. click on pack extension
4. set root directory (folder in which your images and manifest file
   exist)
5. pack extension
6. now disable developer options
7. go to root directory (do not open root directory saying this only so
   that you could easily find file otherwise you can open it)
8. you will see a .crx file just open it with chrome (e.g. drag and drop this file onto the `chrome://extensions/` page)
9. click on continue (will come at the bottom of chrome window)

Your Chrome browser is modified like you wanted